# How to get the Edittext input type in Android when softkeyboard is displayed

Tags: java, android

How to get or know which Input type is been shown by the softkeyboard when the keyboard is displayed in an edittext in Android .Since I want to keep the memory of the input type of edittext even if the data get notified and changes the input type I want to maintain the inputtype in my local variable.

I.e my requirement is when I am manually changing the edit text to numeric and type something the edittext,Edittext sends an event to the server and data gets changed , after that when I press again to modify the value in the edit text ,the keyboard changes to alphabetic keyboard .This I want to avoid ,I want to remain the Softkeyboard to be in numeric,so I want to get the Input type displayed in the keyboard. So how can I get the Input type of Edittext displayed in the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

```
String yourEditTextInputType;
        int editTextType = someEditText.getInputType();
        switch (editTextType) {
            case (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT): {
                yourEditTextInputType = "Name ";
            }
            break;
             case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE: {
                yourEditTextInputType = "Phone Number ";
            }
            break;
            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME: {
                yourEditTextInputType = "Date ";
            }
            break;
            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER: {
                yourEditTextInputType = "Number ";
            }
            break;
            case InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS: {
                yourEditTextInputType = "Address ";
            }
            break;
            case (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT): {
                yourEditTextInputType = "Password or Confirm Password ";
            }
            break;
            case (InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT): {
                yourEditTextInputType = "Email ";
            }
            break;

            default: {
                yourEditTextInputType = "Field ";
            }
            break;
        }

      Log.d("TYPE",yourEditTextInputType);

      // Handle your logic of displaying keyboard , depending on input type
```

Comment: What if the user changes the type actually I want the current keyboard type